# How to filter array with NSPredicate for combination of words

Tags: ios, nspredicate

```
[filteredArray filterUsingPredicate:
   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", searchText]];
```

`filteredArray` contains simple NSStrings. [hello, my, get, up, seven, etc...];

It will give all strings that begin with `searchText`.

But if string will be a combination of words like "my name is", and `searchText = name`. What would a `NSPredicate` look like to achieve this?

UPDATE:
And how would it have to be if i want to a result with `searchText = name`, but not with `searchText = ame`? Maybe like this:

```
 [filteredArray filterUsingPredicate:
       [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
        @"self BEGINSWITH[cd] %@ or self CONTENTS[cd] %@", 
        searchText, searchText]];
```

But it should first display the strings that begin with `searchText` and only after those which contain `searchText`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText];
```

**EDIT after expansion of question**

```
NSArray *beginMatch = [filteredArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
    @"self BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", searchText]];
NSArray *anyMatch = [filteredArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
    @"self CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText]];

NSMutableArray *allResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:beginMatch];
for (id obj in anyMatch) {
   if (![allResults containsObject:obj]) {
      [allResults addObject:obj];
   }
}
filteredArray = allResults;
```

This will have the results in the desired order without duplicate entries.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**  Actually beginsWith check from start of string to search string length. if exact match found then its filtered

```
if u have name game tame lame
search Text : ame
filtered text would be: none
```

contains also check from start of string to search string length but if found start, middle or end exact search string then it is filtered.

```
if u have name game tame lame
search Text : ame
filtered text would be: name game tame lame because all has ame
```

---

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self CONTAINS '%@'", searchText];
```